# Trivial string-reverser in MASM64

Tags: beginner, assembly, winapi, amd64

I've been learning MASM64 over the last few days and written a simple demo, so I can get feedback on my understanding of x64 assembly programming.

It's really basic: it asks the user for their name, greets them, and then reverses the name string.

The point of this question is to get a confirmation I understand the basic stuff like calling convention, stack alignment, etc. correctly. It's surely **not** about performance.

The complete code:

```
extrn GetStdHandle : proc
extrn WriteConsoleA : proc
extrn ReadConsoleA : proc

.const
    STDIN_HANDLE_ID equ -10
    STDOUT_HANDLE_ID equ -11
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE equ -1
    NULL equ 0
    
.data
    promptText db "Enter your name: ", 0
    greetingText db "Hello, ", 0
    backwardsText db "Your name backwards is: ", 0
    
.code

;   Counts characters in a null-terminated string.
;   Parameters:
;       1. Pointer to string.
;   Return value:
;       -> string length (without the terminator).
;
stringLength proc
    ;   No need for shadow space.
    mov rdx, rcx
    mov rcx, -1
    
    _nextChar:
    inc rcx
    mov al, byte ptr [rdx + rcx]
    test al, al
    jnz _nextChar
    
    mov rax, rcx
    ret
stringLength endp
    
;   Displays a null-terminated string.
;   Parameters:
;       1. Pointer to string to be displayed.
;       2. Number of characters to be displayed.
;   Return value:
;       -> On success: 0.
;       -> On failure: -1.
;
stringPrint proc
    ;   Reserve shadow space.
    sub rsp, 48h
    
    ;   Save string address for later use.
    mov [rsp + 38h], rcx    
    
    call stringLength
    
    ;   If (length == 0), just end the function.
    test rax, rax
    jz _stringPrintEnd
    
    ;   Save string length for later use.
    mov [rsp + 40h], rax
    
    mov rcx, STDOUT_HANDLE_ID
    call GetStdHandle
    
    cmp rax, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    je _stringPrintEnd
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], NULL
    mov r9, NULL
    mov r8d, [rsp + 40h]
    mov rdx, [rsp + 38h]
    mov rcx, rax    ;   console handle
    call WriteConsoleA
    
    test rax, rax
    jz _stringPrintError

    xor rax, rax
    _stringPrintEnd:
    ;   Free shadow space.
    add rsp, 48h
    ret

    _stringPrintError:  
    mov rax, -1
    jmp _stringPrintEnd
    
stringPrint endp
    
;   Reads count-1 characters from the standard input.
;   Parameters:
;       1. Pointer to buffer to store the characters.
;       2. Character count.
;   Return value:
;       -> On success: 0.
;       -> On error: -1.
;
stringRead proc
    ;   Reserve shadow space.
    sub rsp, 48h
    
    ;   Save volatile registers for later use.
    mov [rsp + 38h], rcx
    mov [rsp + 40h], rdx
    
    mov rcx, STDIN_HANDLE_ID
    call GetStdHandle
    
    cmp rax, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    je _stringReadError
    
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], NULL
    lea r9, [rsp + 28h]
    mov r8, [rsp + 40h]
    mov rdx, [rsp + 38h]
    mov rcx, rax
    call ReadConsoleA
    
    test rax, rax
    jz _stringReadError
    
    xor rax, rax
    _stringReadError:
    
    ;   Free shadow space.
    add rsp, 48h
    ret
stringRead endp
    
;   Reverses a null-terminated string.
;   Parameters:
;       1. Pointer to string to be reversed.
;       2. Pointer to buffer to store the output.
;
stringReverse proc
    ;   Reserve shadow space.
    sub rsp, 38h
    
    ;   Save volatile registers.
    mov [rsp + 28h], rcx    ;   src buffer
    mov [rsp + 30h], rdx    ;   dst buffer
    
    ;   RCX is already set.
    call stringLength
    
    test rax, rax
    jz _stringReverseEnd
    
    mov rcx, [rsp + 28h]    
    dec rcx
    
    mov rdx, [rsp + 30h]
    add rdx, rax
    
    ;   Terminate the dst buffer.
    mov byte ptr [rdx], 0   
    
    _reverseNextChar:
    inc rcx
    dec rdx
    mov al, byte ptr [rcx]
    
    ;   Check for terminator in src buffer.
    test al, al 
    jz _stringReverseEnd
    
    mov byte ptr [rdx], al 
    jmp _reverseNextChar
    
    _stringReverseEnd:
    xor rax, rax
    ;   Free shadow space.
    add rsp, 38h
    ret
stringReverse endp
    

main proc
    ;   Reserve shadow space: 20h for calls + 28h for buffers.
    sub rsp, 48h    
    
    ;   Zero the buffers.
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 30h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 38h], 0
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 40h], 0
    
    lea rcx, promptText 
    call stringPrint
    
    mov rdx, 14h
    lea rcx, [rsp + 20h]    ;   reading buffer
    call stringRead
    
    lea rdx, [rsp + 34h]    ;   destination buffer
    lea rcx, [rsp + 20h]    ;   source buffer
    call stringReverse
    
    lea rcx, greetingText
    call stringPrint
    
    lea rcx, [rsp + 20h]
    call stringPrint
    
    lea rcx, backwardsText
    call stringPrint
    
    lea rcx, [rsp + 34h]
    call stringPrint
    
    xor rax, rax
    ;   Free shadow space.
    add rsp, 48h
    ret
main endp

end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *stringLength* leaf function (no prolog/epilog) could still be a bit simpler:

```
stringLength proc
    mov rax, -1
  _nextChar:
    inc rax
    cmp byte ptr [rcx + rax], 0
    jne _nextChar
    ret
stringLength endp
```

---

The comments on the *stringPrint* frame function suggest that a second parameter exists.

```
;   Displays a null-terminated string.
;   Parameters:
;       1. Pointer to string to be displayed.
;       2. Number of characters to be displayed.
```

This is not the case.

When the call to *GetStdHandle* fails, you jump to *_stringPrintEnd* where I think you could jump to *_stringPrintError*.

The 5th parameter for *WriteConsoleA*, the one that goes onto the stack, must go to `[rsp + 20h]` right above the register home area. You wrote `[rsp + 28h]`.

A simpler exit is:

```
  test rax, rax
  mov  rax, -1
  jz   _stringPrintEnd
  xor  rax, rax
_stringPrintEnd:
  add  rsp, 48h
  ret
```

---

The exit from the *stringRead* frame function is not very useful. It will always return `RAX=0`. In other words: the test is redundant.

```
  test rax, rax
  jz   _stringReadError
  xor  rax, rax
_stringReadError:
```

---

In the *stringReverse* proc, it is easy to write the loop using a single conditional jump, omitting the second jump. I know that you're not seeking performance but then again this is assembly...

```
  mov  al, 0      ; To terminate the dst buffer.
_reverseNextChar:
  inc  rcx
  mov  [rdx], al
  dec  rdx
  mov  al, [rcx]
  test al, al 
  jnz  _reverseNextChar
```

---

### Some ideas

- Instead of determining the string length yourself, why don't you use the *lpNumberOfCharsRead* that you receive from invoking *ReadConsoleA*?
- Why do you bother to zero your source and destination buffers. That's not a useful operation (unless you doubt that the input from *ReadConsoleA* will be zero-terminated by default).
  And if you insist on clearing these buffers then please try not to use that many bytes. Next is much smaller:

  ```
    xor  eax, eax
    mov  [rsp + 20h], rax
    mov  [rsp + 28h], rax
    mov  [rsp + 30h], rax
    mov  [rsp + 38h], rax
    mov  [rsp + 40h], rax
  ```
- It will be much nicer if you introduced a couple of newlines in the output:

  ```
    greetingText db 13, 10, "Hello, ", 0
    backwardsText db 13, 10, "Your name backwards is: ", 0
  ```

> The point of this question is to get a confirmation I understand the basic stuff like calling convention, stack alignment, etc. correctly.

Except for that 5th parameter on *WriteConsoleA*, this seems to be fine. Well done.

For maximum adherence to the conventions you could store the register parameters `RCX` and `RDX` in the shadow memory that the caller had to set aside for that purpose.
Below is how it changes *stringRead* (similar for *stringPrint* and *stringReverse*):

````
stringRead proc
    ;   Save volatile registers in register home area for later use.
    mov [rsp + 8], rcx
    mov [rsp + 16], rdx
    ;   Reserve shadow space, local storage and alignment
    sub rsp, 38h
        
    mov rcx, STDIN_HANDLE_ID
    call GetStdHandle
    
    ...
    
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], NULL
    lea r9, [rsp + 28h]
    mov r8, [rsp + 38h + 16]
    mov rdx, [rsp + 38h + 8]
    mov rcx, rax
    call ReadConsoleA
    
    ...

    add rsp, 38h
    ret
stringRead endp
```
````

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read it and for your commentary. I can't believe I didn't spot at least some of those errors, haha. Also, the suggestion to use the caller-allocated shadow space was an eye-opener, made me realize I didn't **fully** understand the convention. Once again - thanks!

Comment: Since this is x86-64, the standard way to store a bunch of zeros is with SSE or SSE2.  `xorps xmm0,xmm0` / `movaps [rsp + 20h], xmm0` etc.  (With the last store being `movlps [rsp+40h], xmm0` if you need to store an odd multiple of 8.)